# wicket sessions: how to prevent "jsessionid" from showing up in googlebot crawl results?

Tags: wicket, session-state, jsessionid

When google crawls our site the resulting URLs all have the `jsessionid` appended to them. 
Is this happening because the app server is detecting a lack of cookie support in Googlebot, forcing the session to be maintained via URL-rewriting? Is there anything I can do about it?

Is the solution simply to never call `Component.getSession()` ? Is there anything like `HttpServletRequest.getSession(false)` ?

**Edit:** just found `org.apache.wicket.Session.exists()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution in [SEO - Search Engine Optimization - Apache Wicket Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/SEO+-+Search+Engine+Optimization).

In a nutshell:

- override `WebApplication.newWebResponse()`
- have it return a `BufferedWebResponse` that checks to see if the user-agent is a crawler (i.e. googlebot) or not
- if it's a crawler, don't re-write the URL

Comment: the link was moved to: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/SEO+-+Search+Engine+Optimization